# Example page for trying out web automation tools

Tags: web-testing

Does anybody know of a web page which I can try out automation tools on.

We are evaluating a Test Automation tool and are looking for a page where we can write test cases to automate that are beyond the average "Google search" test case.

So I am looking for a page which is a bit more advanced, for example with Login, Search. And it should be built for trying out test automation, and nobody should care if we fill it with crazy data.

An example would be this page: http://www.ranorex.com/web-testing-examples/vip/

But I would like some more advance stuff, multiple pages and login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a few dummy Google accounts: that would give you the ability to test multiple simultaneous logins and access to a myriad of different activities (Gmail, Google+) that have some pretty advanced capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

One simple out of the box website is the asp.net internet template site that comes with asp.net MVC. Just load up Visual Studio (even express) and create the site automatically.

I would consider that a decent playground. It is also easy to add on new functionality to it since all the plumbing is there